# Power Query. Combine the first two rows

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a spreadsheet with Year in row 1, and Month in row 2.

I need to combine them into dates before promoting the resulting row into a header row.

The data looks like this:

```
2017, 2017, 2017,...
Jan , Feb,  Mar ,...
```

I'm trying to get:

```
Jan 2017, Feb 2017, Mar 2017,...
```

I've read this but can't find information about relative column references [Absolute & Relative References](http://excel-inside.pro/blog/2015/11/05/absolute-and-relative-references-in-power-query/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Transpose table
2. Merge first two columns
3. Transpose again

[Link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Merge-2-rows-in-one-row/td-p/46144)

Comment: I was thinking that your answer was too simplistic without showing the M code but it really is this easy from the buttons on the ribbon.